# Push notification in background (PHP)

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

Currently I am using APNS PHP for push notification. The problem is I can't respond to the client after it has finished the process and I need to wait until apple responds for the push notification.

I don't want to wait for the push notification; I want to make the push notification in a background process or other thread. Is this possible?

I found the other solution in stackoverflow; some advise one to use a cron job to make it run in the background. But I don't prefer this way. Is there some other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it asynchronous - put it in queue.

Does Apple return anything for Push? I've been working with APNS for years and never got any response, even after they extended API with error codes.

Comment: I am using APNS PHP, you can check http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/wiki/SampleOutput

Comment: If I didn't use Push , server respond in 2 seconds. If I use the Push , server respond in 10 seconds. It may be problem of connecting to server with curl.

Comment: I know this library - it's very clumsy. Search for APNS approaches in google. Actually, you don't need this lib and if you send it with custom implementation it would cost you ~1.5sec (sending to few devices).